# getting 10 random entries for each category

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, random, postgresql-9.1

I have this table

**topic_categories**-> has many -> **topic_sub_categories** -> has many -> **topics** -> has many ->**questions** -> **choices**

What I want to do it to get 10 random questions per topic_sub_categories given topic_category_id

I already did it using SQL query

```
SELECT x.*
FROM (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.TopicSubCatId) AS rowNumber,
    t.*
    FROM (
         SELECT abc.TopicSubCatId as TopicSubCatId, q.id as QuestionId, q.*
         FROM questions q
         LEFT JOIN topics t on t.id = q.topic_id
         LEFT JOIN (SELECT tsc.id as TopicSubCatId
              FROM topic_categories tc 
              LEFT JOIN topic_sub_categories tsc ON tc.id = tsc.topic_category_id 
              WHERE tsc.id IS NOT NULL 
              AND tc.id = 1 
              GROUP BY tsc.id, tsc.name) abc ON t.topic_sub_category_id = abc.TopicSubCatId
         ) t) x
where x.rowNumber <= 3
order by random()
```

the problem is, I want to eager load the choices per question
so that my my view would look like:

```
-@questions.each do |q|
  q.choices.order("RANDOM()").each do |c|
  end
end
```

could you suggest on how to do the query using active record or any other approach to my problem.

BTW: i'm using postgresql

Comment: Make a method on the `Question` model that does this for you. Then, you can do `q.random_choices.each do |c|`

Comment: I could do that If I could translate the query into active record. I could only execute that query via ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute() and this will not return a Question object

Comment: checkout [arel](https://github.com/rails/arel).

Comment: Whenever I end up with complicated queries that I want to use in rails, I try to start breaking them down into the dependent models and then writing scopes for each of the models. Then you can chain scopes together to create the aggregate query

Comment: Agree with Peter's approach